# SQL join - result in single row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to join two SQL tables to get a result in a single line

Table 1

```
id     | num    | value        (Values can be 'N' number)
------ | ------ | ------
X      | 1      | ZA  
X      | 2      | Z1
```

Table 2

```
id     | num    | num2
------ | ------ | ------
X      | 1      | 2
```

Joing table 1 and table 2

What I got:

```
id     | num    | value  | num    | value
------ | ------ | ------ | ------ | ------
X      | 1      | ZA     | 2      | null   
X      | 1      | null   | 2      | Z1
```

Expected result:

```
id     | num    | value  | num    | value
------ | ------ | ------ | ------ | ------
X      | 1      | ZA     | 2      | Z1
```

How can I do that?

Comment: You need to elaborate a bit, and provide your query.

Comment: You should use aggregation and a GROUP BY, but to @scsimon's point, you haven't provided us enough detail to tell you how.  What are the rules for collapsing different values, which take precedent, etc...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Select t1.id, t1a.num, t1a.value, t1b.num, t1b.value
from table2 t2
left join table1 t1a on t2.num = t1a.num
left join table1 t1b on t2.num2 = t1b.num
```

Comment: I would add equality on the `id` columns as well; it seems like a reasonable interpretation of the question.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Hogan :)